# How to properly initialize a create table servlet in JDBC?

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc

I have a problem with creating tables in my database in Java. I have created methods to create DB properly:

```
/**
 * (@inheritDoc)
 * StartingServlet this Servlet, and create the database.
 * 
 * @throws javax.servlet.ServletException
 */
@Override
public void init() throws ServletException {
    if (SQLConnector.getConnection() == null){
        if (SQLConnector.tryConnection(this.getServletContext())){
            this.connection = SQLConnector.getConnection();
            this.initializeTableDisc();
            this.initializeTableAuthor();
            System.out.println("Connected and created DBs!");
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Method for creating a table, with statement.
 * @param sqlQuery what string to use to create a table
 */
private void createTable(String sqlQuery){
    try {
        Statement statement = this.connection.createStatement();
        statement.executeQuery(sqlQuery);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {

    }
}

/**
 * Creates a table for Discs.
 */
private void initializeTableDisc(){
    this.createTable("CREATE TABLE Discs (" +
            "discID INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            "discName VARCHAR(20), " +
            "authorID INTEGER NOT NULL, discPrice FLOAT" +
            "PRIMARY KEY (discID) )");
}

/**
 * Creates a table for Authors.
 */
private void initializeTableAuthor(){
    this.createTable("CREATE TABLE Authors (" +
            "authorID INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            "authorName VARCHAR(30), " + 
            "authorSurname VARCHAR(30), " + 
            "PRIMARY KEY (authorID) )");
}
```

With a SQLConnector class

```
public final class SQLConnector {

private static Connection connection = null;

public static boolean tryConnection(ServletContext context) {
    if (connection == null){
        try {
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(context.getInitParameter("url"), 
                    context.getInitParameter("login"), context.getInitParameter("password"));
        } catch (SQLException | NullPointerException | ClassNotFoundException ex){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

/**
 * Try and close the connection.
 */
public static void closeConnection(){
    try {
        connection.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.getMessage();
    }
}

/**
 * Getter for a connection.
 * 
 * @return connection which is used
 */
public static Connection getConnection(){
    return connection;
}
}
```

My snippet from web.xml file

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>url</param-name>
    <param-value>jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/musicdatabase</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>login</param-name>
    <param-value>test</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>password</param-name>
    <param-value>test</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <description>Startup servlet</description>
    <servlet-name>StartingServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>pl.polsl.java.pawel.kucia.servlets.StartingServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
```

What am I doing wrong here? When debugging, it seems that it doesnt add properly the databases, it is initialized properly, so maybe its something wrong with the SQL syntax, or the connection. I'm literally out of ideas.

Comment: try with executeUpdate() instead of executeQuery().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For DDL and SQL statements which modify the database you need to use

```
statement.executeUpdate(sql);
```

but in your `createTable` method you use `statement.executeQuery()`.

Comment: 2h wasted for this :D